# How to maintaing user last login date and time in php currently showing today date but i want to display last one when i logedin

Tags: php

```
<?php

 $sql="update user_login set Last_Login=now() where User_Id='$someId'"
mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

How to maintaing user last login date and time in php currentrly showing today date but i want to display last one when i logedin ...

Answer (score 0):

You just can save the "LastSession", and, the "currentSession".

When user log in, you save the "currentSession" on the "lastSession", and you save the current date on the "currentSession"...

Or, you just get the "last_login" before update it...